# SQL query to exclude records based on type and dates

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

ORIGINAL

```
 match_date actual_date      colA        type   type_desc
 09/16/11   10/1/2011        ABC12345    A      TTT222
 09/16/11   10/8/2011        ABC12345    S      BADTYPE_123
 09/16/11   11/8/2011        ABC12345    A      YYY222
 09/16/11   11/8/2011        ABC12345    A      WWW333
 09/16/11   11/8/2011        ABC12345    B      YYY222
 09/16/11   11/8/2011        ABC12345    B      WWW333   
 05/11/12   9/17/2012        ABC12345    B      ZZZ222
 05/11/12   9/17/2012        ABC12345    A      ZZZ222
 05/11/12   9/17/2012        MNO12345    B      CCC222
 05/11/12   9/17/2012        MNO12345    A      CCC222
 08/16/12   10/8/2011        MNO12345    S      BADTYPE_789
 08/16/12   10/9/2011        MNO12345    A      CCC111
 11/11/12   11/17/2012       MNO12345    S      BADTYPE_790
 12/01/12   9/17/2012        MNO12345    A      DDD222
 11/20/12   1/06/2013        XYZ98765    B      TST111
 11/20/12   1/06/2013        XYZ98765    A      TST111
 01/15/13   3/17/2013        XYZ98765    A      TST222
 05/11/13   6/15/2013        XYZ98765    B      TST111
 05/11/13   9/15/2013        XYZ98765    A      TST111
```

For each given match_date "group" (colA and Match date, ABC12345 and 09/16/11 and ABC12345 05/11/12 in first "group" example), if a record is type "S" and contains "BADTYPE*" as the type_desc, I want to exclude/delete all records between the "BADTYPE" actual_date and the next match_date for a given "match_date group".

If there are no "BADTYPE" records for a given "match_date group", it should be ignored.  If the only record for a given match_date group is the BADTYPE record, then it will remain and continue.

RECORDS TO BE DELETED

```
 match_date actual_date      colA        type   type_desc
 09/16/11   11/8/2011        ABC12345    A      YYY222
 09/16/11   11/8/2011        ABC12345    A      WWW333
 09/16/11   11/8/2011        ABC12345    B      YYY222
 09/16/11   11/8/2011        ABC12345    B      WWW333   
 08/16/12   10/9/2011        MNO12345    A      CCC111
```

FINAL RESULTS WITH RECORDS REMOVED

```
 match_date actual_date      colA        type   type_desc
 09/16/11   10/1/2011        ABC12345    A      TTT222
 09/16/11   10/8/2011        ABC12345    S      BADTYPE_123  
 05/11/12   9/17/2012        ABC12345    B      ZZZ222
 05/11/12   9/17/2012        ABC12345    A      ZZZ222
 05/11/12   9/17/2012        MNO12345    B      CCC222
 05/11/12   9/17/2012        MNO12345    A      CCC222
 08/16/12   10/8/2011        MNO12345    S      BADTYPE_789
 11/11/12   11/17/2012       MNO12345    S      BADTYPE_790
 12/01/12   9/17/2012        MNO12345    A      DDD222
 11/20/12   1/06/2013        XYZ98765    B      TST111
 11/20/12   1/06/2013        XYZ98765    A      TST111
 01/15/13   3/17/2013        XYZ98765    A      TST222
 05/11/13   6/15/2013        XYZ98765    B      TST111
 05/11/13   9/15/2013        XYZ98765    A      TST111
```

Hopefully I've fully illustrated exactly what I'm trying to do.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest and fastest way to do it is to use windowed functions [LEAD and LAG](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx), but as far as you are using SQL Server 2008, it's not possible for you.
In SQL Server 2008, you could use [outer apply](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - basically what you need is to get previous record for given "match_group" ordered by `actual_date` descending and delete record if previous `type_desc like 'BADTYPE%' and type = 'S'`

When you decide what you need, you could pretty easily transcribe that algorithm into SQL, and feel the power of declarative languages:

```
delete Table1
from Table1 as T1
    cross apply
    (
        select top 1 T2.[type_desc], T2.[type]
        from Table1 as T2
        where T2.ColA = T1.ColA and T2.match_date = T1.match_date and T2.[actual_date] < T1.[actual_date]
        order by T2.[actual_date] desc
    ) as PR
where PR.[type_desc] like 'BADTYPE%' and PR.[type] = 'S'
```

you could also check [**SQL FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b832c/8) to see how it's working

Comment: Both solutions seem to be working... I'm running some more tests as we speak.  Can either one of you recommend a good book or website to help me with learning more advanced TSQL programming skills?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a recursive query for this.
Something like this:

```
SELECT *, 
       Row_number() 
         OVER ( 
           PARTITION BY COLA, MATCH_DATE 
           ORDER BY ACTUAL_DATE) RN 
INTO   #TEMP1 
FROM   TABLE1; 

WITH CTE 
     AS (SELECT *, 
                Cast(1 AS INT) AS flag 
         FROM   #TEMP1 
         WHERE  RN = 1 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT t1.*, 
                CASE 
                  WHEN T2.FLAG = 2 
                        OR ( t2.TYPE_DESC LIKE 'BADTYPE%' 
                             AND t2.TYPE = 'S' ) THEN 2 
                  ELSE 1 
                END flag 
         FROM   #TEMP1 T1 
                INNER JOIN CTE T2 
                        ON T1.COLA = T2.COLA 
                           AND t1.MATCH_DATE = t2.MATCH_DATE 
                           AND t1.RN = T2.RN + 1) 
SELECT [MATCH_DATE], 
       [ACTUAL_DATE], 
       [COLA], 
       [TYPE], 
       [TYPE_DESC] 
FROM   CTE 
WHERE  FLAG = 1 
ORDER  BY COLA, 
          MATCH_DATE
```

You can play around with a working example on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7b600/22).

Good luck!

Comment: Both solutions seem to be working... I'm running some more tests as we speak.  Can either one of you recommend a good book or website to help me with learning more advanced TSQL programming skills?

Comment: Both solutions work great, the first one seems to solve my issue with less code and less resources.  Thanks!